# Как мне вывести числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Есть много реквизитов в тексте.
Например: А15632, А14752, А12345...

Мне надо вырезать каждую отдельно:

```
parsed_req = 'А15632RT, А14752RT, А12345RT...'
requisites = re.findall(r'>\d{5}', parsed_req)
```

вот так дает результат:

А15632 A14752 итд

пишу так а он не работает:

```
parsed_req = 'А15632RT, А14752RT, А12345RT...'
requisites = re.findall(r'>\d{5}', parsed_req)
requisites2 = re.sub(r'A','',requisites)
```

пишу на python 3.6

Comment: `>` не находит `A`. Как у вас `re.findall(r'>\d{5}', 'А15632RT, А14752RT, А12345RT...')` даёт результат *`А15632 A14752 итд`*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

parsed_req = 'А15632RT, А14752RT, А12345RT...'
```

Просто выцепляем 5 подряд идущих цифр:

```
requisites = re.findall(r'\d{5}', parsed_req)
print(requisites)  # ['15632', '14752', '12345']
```

С указанием специализированного шаблона поиска цифр:

```
requisites = re.findall(r'А(\d{5})RT', parsed_req)
print(requisites)  # ['15632', '14752', '12345']
```

**PS.**

У вас в примерах с `А` символ русский, что странно при наличии латинских `RT`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, а насчет символов это опечатка. сорри.

Comment: Кстати можно узнать как вы заметили что символ А русский?

Comment: @Student, опыт :) уже не в первый раз с подобным сталкиваюсь, поэтому когда моя регулярка с указанными `A` и `RT` не смогла найти числа в `parsed_req` сразу подумал на `A` ну и проверил код символа через `ord`. У кириллицы код будет 4-х значным, а у латиницы двухзначным `print(ord('A'), ord('А'))  # 65 1040`

Comment: Классно! Спасибо большое!